# MacOS Mojave path problem with import csv in python

Tags: python, macos, csv, python-import

I got Mojave on my MAC and now, with this kind of OS, the path of a file is the following:

**"Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨utents ▸ ⁨name ▸ ⁨desktop ▸ ⁨folder_name ▸ ⁨file_name.csv"**

The problem is that python does not recognize this kind of path with the **"▸"**.

I've already tried to convert the arrows with the **"/"** but nothing happened.

Any suggestion?

I don't know how to import the file!

Comment: What happens if you open the terminal ad type `⁨ls -l /⁨Utenti⁩/Dario⁩/⁨Scrivania⁩/⁨OMML⁩/⁨HW1⁩/DATA.csv` ?

Comment: @Dario after many proposed suggestions and comments, it's still unclear what your problem is. Since you are not giving any extra information I'm going to vote to close this question.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for your help. I've found a blog where it has explained how to grab the path with the "/" and now it works.
Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the name of the HD and all spaces around the separator:

```
/⁨utents/⁨name/⁨desktop/⁨folder_name/⁨file_name.csv
```

If this refers to an external disk, you probably need to look in `/Volumes/` and check the mount point of that disk, it will be something like:

```
/⁨Volumes/Macintosh HD/⁨name/⁨desktop/⁨folder_name/⁨file_name.csv
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: File b'\xe2\x81\xa8/\xe2\x81\xa8Utenti\xe2\x81\xa9/Dario\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8Scrivania\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8OMML\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8HW1\xe2\x81\xa9/DATA.csv' does not exist

Comment: There are extra characters in your string - see the `\xe2\x81\xa8/\xe2\x81\xa8`. You need to remove this, so that you are left with just a / between the parts of the path. Can you post the exact code you are using?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv("⁨/⁨Utenti⁩/Dario⁩/⁨Scrivania⁩/⁨OMML⁩/⁨HW1⁩/DATA.csv")

Comment: The first example here is not a valid path. The second one **looks** like a valid path but isn't. Make sure to remove every / and the (invisible) characters around it and replace it with a /. You want to get rid of the `\xe2\x81\xa8/\xe2\x81\xa8` : characters you cannot see.

Comment: I'll keep going to try but sincerely I don't know what else I could do.

Comment: Well maybe just copy the path by hand? The problem is that the code you are using right now contains invisible characters that make the path invalid. What you want to do is enter a valid path, that does not contain these characters. One way is to just type the path in yourself.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly did you do? What output did it give? This way it is not possible to help you.

Comment: I've told you. I've just tried to import a csv file as always. Just that one command line. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've probably resolved this by now, but for future reference you can use the function below to clean a mac filepath:

```
#clean Mac mojave file paths

def fp_cleaner (fp_in):
    fp_in_str = str(fp_in)
    fp_out = fp_in_str.replace("Macintosh HD","").replace("⁩ ▸ ⁨", "/").replace("⁩", "")
    print("'"+fp_out+'/'+"'")
    return;

fp_cleaner(fp_in = 'YOUR FILE PATH HERE⁩')
```

Instructions:

1. Select file you are trying to import
2. Command+i (this is the equivalent to right click and select "Get Info")
3. Copy the "Where:" info under "General" (i.e., your file path in Mac format) and paste as `fp_in = 'YOUR FILE PATH HERE'`

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem but thanks for your suggestion.